Slow SOAP Request Response with node-soap Library for Large Data Set
I'm using the node-soap library in Node.js to make a SOAP request. Here's my code:
const Get_Workers_Method = client['Human_ResourcesService']['Human_Resources']['Get_Workers'];

Get_Workers_Method(Get_Workers_Args, (err, result, rawResponse, soapHeader) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Result:', JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
    console.log('Request:', JSON.stringify(Get_Workers_Args, null, 2));
  }
}, clientOptions);

When I try to get 100 users, it takes almost 5 minutes to get the response. However, if I request data for just one user, the response is quick. I suspect that the delay is due to the node-soap library's parsing process.
Is there a way to disable parsing in node-soap or any other solution to speed up the response time for large data sets?
